# How to pass greater than or less than operator in guzzle http when doing request

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, oauth, guzzle

How can I send a request correctly with query string greater than operator using guzzle?
Here I want to pull all records with dateLastModified greater than specific date

```
$this->client = new Client([
            'base_uri'  => $base_url . $version . '/',
            'handler'   => $stack,
            'auth'      => 'oauth'
        ]);

$query_string = "?filter=status='active'&dateLastModified>" . "'"$some_date"'" . "&limit=500";
$response = $this->client->get('/students' . $query_string);
```

I was thrown with the error below. Notice that the greater than symbol is changed

```
filter=status='active'&dateLastModified%3E'2021-09-01T16:39:00.000Z'&limit=15000` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response: {"errors":[{"codeMajor":"FAILURE","severity":"ERROR","codeMinor":"UNAUTHORIZED","description":"User not authorized."}]}
```

Comment: can you show what is the request you are sending on postman successfully screenshot

Comment: this works in postman something like this: 
`/v1/students?filter=status='active'&dateLastModified>'2021-08-01T16:39:00.000Z'&limit=15000`

Comment: You get a 401 response. Are you sure it's because of the `>` sign? As Schlotter noticed this is just URL encryption of a sign which can't be normally used in a URL, so it's fine that it is changed to that.

Answer (score 0):

The greater than symbol is encoded. (Because you send a GET and `%3E` is equivalent to `>`)
So decoding it, before sending it to the Database should fix it:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: I tried `$query_string = urlencode($query_string);`and `$query_string = urlencode($query_string);` but I'm still getting the error. I tried the same string in postman and it works. I want to make it work in my code as well